# Pandas evaluate condition and convert to 0/1 int

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to evaluate a dateTimeIndex to determine if a date is equivalent to a specific date and return a new series as a result containing the results of the conditional as 0/1.

My sample in:

```
rng = pd.period_range('2019-11-04', '2019-11-12', freq='D',name="Active_Date").to_timestamp()
```

out:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2019-11-04', '2019-11-05', '2019-11-06', '2019-11-07',
           '2019-11-08', '2019-11-09', '2019-11-10', '2019-11-11',
           '2019-11-12'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Active_Date', freq='D')
```

For example, if my eval criteria is '2019-11-06', I'm looking to return the following:

```
Int64Index([0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
           dtype='int64', name='Active_Date')
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: `(rng == "2019-11-06").astype("int")`?

Comment: This also works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the index with your "eval criteria", then convert the bool result to an Int64Index:

```
pd.Int64Index(rng == '2019-11-06')
# Int64Index([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype='int64')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply compare with `dt.datetime` objects.

```
import datetime as dt

split = series > dt.datetime(2019, 11, 6)
```